# Submitting form with jQuery & validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

I am using validate.js to validate a form. If the form does not validate, a message is displayed when the user tries to submit a form, showing the errors. If the user passes validation, then a success message pops up. The problem is, the form does not actually send/take action, because validate.js is preventing the default behavior.

The code that is preventing the form from sending is:

```
if (event && event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
} else if (event) {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

You can see full js here:  http://jsfiddle.net/DBfks/

It seems to me that the above code prevents default behavior of the form submission IF the form does not pass validation, but if it does, then the form should submit. Is this correct? Any ideas on how to make the form submit INSTEAD of showing a success message (please see jsfiddle to see how the success and error messages work)

Thanks in advance. You can see a working demo [here](http://bajdesign.com/fstesting/contact-us/contact/).

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 $("#myForm").submit();
```

Where you want to submit the form.

In your jsFiddle you got this if/else:

```
if (errors.length > 0) {
                        SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();

                        for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
                            SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors[i].message + '<br />');
                        }

                        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({ display: 'none' });
                        SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);

                    } else {
                        SELECTOR_ERRORS.css({ display: 'none' });
                        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.fadeIn(200);

                    }
```

(Okay, copy-pasting kinda messed it up!)

So, if there were any errors, add al the errors to the error box and show it. else show you validated it. But that isn't what you want, you should submit the form there:

```
else {
    $("#yourform").submit();
}
```

Comment: Im looking to integrate it within the validation code. I tried that outside (using a click event on the submit button), and it did not work (seems prevented by the validate plugin)

Comment: Yes, you should replace the code for the succes Message with this.

Comment: I need help in the context of my problem. That doesnt work by defaults, because the default is prevented.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but this does not work as you would expect. The anser you -1'ed below is a truly workable solution. The code which I posted was preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: And yes, indeed, that code prevented form submission, but it is always triggered. If you remove that, it will even submit if validation failed. @JCHASE11

Comment: It does not submit if validation failed. It works just great this way...Although I understand what you mean- it shouldn't work because nothing is preventing the form from taking action.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the code was not working with jQuery submit was because the preventDefault method prevented jQuery from submitting the form. The fix was to simply remove these lines:

```
if (event && event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
} else if (event) {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: This will submit even if validation failed.